# Prove that Fourier basis is maximal orthonormal set in real L2

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-series, lp-spaces

I have to prove that the Fourier basis

$$ \{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \} \cup \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cos{nt} : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sin{nt} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

is a maximal orthonormal set in $L_2([-\pi, \pi],\mathbb{R})$.

I have already proved that it is orthonormal and that

$$ \{ e^{imt} : m \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

is a maximal orthonormal set in $L_2([-\pi, \pi],\mathbb{C})$.

So now I know that can I express

$$\cos{nt}=\frac{1}{2} (e^{int} + e^{-int}) \quad  \sin{nt}=\frac{i}{2} (e^{int} - e^{-int})$$

but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You have to imitate the proof that $(e^{in\theta})_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} $ is a maximal basis of $H=L^2_{\mathbb{C}}(-\pi,\pi).$ If not, there exists a non zero $f\in H$ such that $\int _{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)e^{-in \theta}d\theta=0$ for all $n$ and use the Bessel equality giving $\|f\|^2$ to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to prove it. I used the following theorem:

Let $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $H$. Then, the following are equivalent

1. $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a maximal orthonormal set in H.
2. For all $x \in H$ such that $\langle x, u_n\rangle=0 \; \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x=0$.

So let $f\in L_2([-\pi,\pi]; \mathbb{R}) \subseteq L_2([-\pi,\pi]; \mathbb{C})$ such that

$$\langle f, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\rangle =\langle f,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cos{nt}\rangle=\langle f,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin{nt}\rangle =0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \neq 0$, then

$$0=\langle f,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cos{nt} \rangle =\langle f, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-int}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{int}\rangle= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \langle f, e^{-int} \rangle + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \langle f, e^{int} \rangle$$

So $\langle f, e^{-int} \rangle = - \langle f, e^{int} \rangle$.

Moreover,

$$0=\langle f,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \sin{nt} \rangle =\langle f, \frac{i}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-int}-\frac{i}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{int}\rangle= -\frac{i}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \langle f, e^{-int} \rangle + \frac{i}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \langle f, e^{int} \rangle$$

So $\langle f, e^{int} \rangle = \langle f, e^{-int} \rangle = - \langle f, e^{int} \rangle \implies \langle f, e^{int} \rangle = \langle f, e^{-int} \rangle =0$

We also have $\langle f, e^{i0t} \rangle = \langle f, 1 \rangle = \sqrt{2\pi} \langle f, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \rangle =0$

Using the theorem, because $\{e^{imt}: m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a maximal orthonormal set we have $f=0$. So the original orthonormal set is maximal.